# Como poner un div, debajo de una fila en HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, tablas

Desarrollo en Angular y tengo mi tabla en mi component.html mas o menos con esta estructura:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-s col-1 fixed">
                   ...
                </th>

                 <th class="col-mb col-2">
                        ...
                 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let product of prices; index as i">

                <td class="options-column fixed">
                    <arrow-svg class="arrow" 
                    [direction]="getArrowDirection(product._id)" 
                     *ngIf="haveIndicators(product)" 
                    (click)="clickInArrow(product)"></arrow-svg>
                </td>

                <td class="observations-column">
                   ...
                </td>

                <div class="indicators" *ngIf="haveIndicators(product) && isIdInArrayParent(product._id)">

                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Como se puede apreciar, tengo 2 columnas y recorro un arreglo y por cada elemento se crea una linea de la tabla.

El problema surge cuando le doy click al componente de `<arrow-svg>`, aparece en pantalla el DIV. El problema es que aparece como si fuese una fila más, al costado de la celda.

El objetivo es que me aparezca abajo como si fuese otra fila,

Intenté varias formas de solucionarlo.

En síntesis:

1. dentro de cada fila `<tr>` creé 2 div, uno donde contiene las filas comunes `<th>` y otro donde está el `class="indicators`. La fila `tr` tenía la propiedad de `flex-direction:column` y el primer div, obviamente como simulaba ser la fila: `flex-direction:row`.
   El problema con esto era que el DIV que simulaba ser la fila, se adaptaba al tamaño de mi primer columna.
   (No sé si esto será por una propiedad de Css o Bootstrap)
2. Intenté que la función que se ejecutaba al presionar el click, tome la fila, y con Javascript inserte una por debajo.
   Esto funcionó, me insertó la fila.
   Pero el problema en este caso es que la fila nueva, dentro tenía un componente de Angular, y no encontré forma de poder insertarlo.

Este es el ejemplo:

```
function addRow(event:any){

    const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(IndicatorsTableComponent);
    console.log(component);
    const tr = event.target.closest('tr');
    const newRow = tr.parentNode.insertRow(1);
    const td = newRow.insertCell();
    td.colSpan = 15; //La tabla tiene 15 filas.
    const indicators = document.createElement('app-indicators-table');
    newRow.appendChild(td).appendChild(indicators);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con el código compartido en la pregunta es que va a generar HTML que no es válido (un `<div>` no puede ser hijo de un `<tr>`) y que por eso va a hacer que la tabla no se vea bien.

En Angular, puedes usar el [elemento `<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container) para generar una estructura que sea válida con dos filas y que no te genere ningún elemento adicional en el DOM que haga que la tabla no sea válida. De ese modo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-s col-1 fixed">
        ...
      </th>

      <th class="col-mb col-2">
        ...
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of prices; index as i">
      <tr>
        <td class="options-column fixed">
          <arrow-svg class="arrow" 
                     [direction]="getArrowDirection(product._id)" 
                     *ngIf="haveIndicators(product)" 
                     (click)="clickInArrow(product)"></arrow-svg>
        </td>
        <td class="observations-column">
          ...
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="indicators" 
          *ngIf="haveIndicators(product) && isIdInArrayParent(product._id)">
        <td colspan="2">
          ALGO AQUÍ
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Estos son los cambios que hice:

- Añadí un `<ng-container>` que me permita añadir una estructura HTML con dos filas de tabla en vez de una sola.
- Moví el `*ngFor` del `<tr>` al `<ng-container>`, de ese modo el bucle repetirá el contenido del contenedor (pero sin añadir nada extra al DOM).
- En lugar de un `<div>`, añadí una nueva fila con una única celda con `colspan="2"` para que ocupe todo el ancho (deberás cambiar el valor del `colspan` si tienes más columnas).

Y con eso ya me funcionó. Puedes ver una demo (simplificada porque no tenía las funciones disponibles) en [este CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-phoebe-92xjy9?file=/src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Me sirvió, era tal cual lo que quería hacer, muchas gracias. Desconocía esa caracteristica del ng-container. Voy a empezar a emplearlo más. Gracias!!

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara :)